React Native Project Error after expo@51 update
Same Error on Each Screen in my app
Expo Camera Error after update
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { Text, View, StyleSheet, TouchableOpacity, Image, ScrollView, Alert } from "react-native";
import { Camera } from "expo-camera";
import { useNavigation } from "@react-navigation/native";
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage';
import * as Animatable from 'react-native-animatable';
import { Ionicons } from '@expo/vector-icons';
import * as Location from 'expo-location';

const Doscan = () => {
  const [hasPermission, setHasPermission] = useState(null);
  const [scanned, setScanned] = useState(false);
  const [scannedData, setScannedData] = useState([]);
  const navigate = useNavigation();
  const [isPopped, setIsPopped] = useState(false);
  const [isSelectionPhase, setIsSelectionPhase] = useState(false);
  const [torchOn, setTorchOn] = useState(false);
  const [startTime, setStartTime] = useState(null);
  const [endTimeNow, setEndTime] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
      const { status } = await Camera.requestCameraPermissionsAsync();
      setHasPermission(status === "granted");
    })();
    getScannedData();

    return () => {
      setScannedData([]);
    };
  }, []);

  const getScannedData = async () => {
    const data = await AsyncStorage.getItem('scannedData');
    if (data) {
      const parsedData = JSON.parse(data);
      setScannedData(parsedData);
    }
  };

  const handleBarCodeScanned = async ({ data }) => {
    const updatedData = { data, selected: false };
    if (Array.isArray(scannedData) && !scannedData.some((item) => item.data === data)) {
      setScanned(true);
      setScannedData((prevData) => [...prevData, updatedData]);
      await AsyncStorage.setItem('scannedData', JSON.stringify([...scannedData, updatedData]));
    }
    if (!startTime) {
      startTimer(); 
    }
  };

  const pop = async () => {
    setIsPopped(!isPopped);
  };

  const rescan = async () => {
    setScannedData([]);
    await AsyncStorage.removeItem('scannedData');
  };
  

  const showScannedDataAlert = () => {
    Alert.alert(
      "Scanned Data Detail",
      `\nScanned Data:\n\n- ${scannedData.map((item) => item.data).join("\n- ")}`,
      [
        {
          text: "OK",
          onPress: () => {
            setScanned(false);
          },
        },
      ],
    );
  };
  

  const handleItemPress = (index) => {
    if (isSelectionPhase) {
      const newData = [...scannedData];
      newData[index].selected = !newData[index].selected;
      setScannedData(newData);
    }
  };

  const handleCheckButtonPress = () => {
    setIsSelectionPhase(true);
  };

  const toggleTorch = () => {
    setTorchOn((prev) => !prev);
  };

  const cancel = () =>{
    setIsSelectionPhase(false);
    const newData = scannedData.map(item => ({ ...item, selected: false }));
    setScannedData(newData);
  };

  const confirm = () => {
    setIsSelectionPhase(false);
  };

  const startTimer = () => {
    setStartTime(Date.now());
    console.log('Timer Started');
  };

  const endTimer = () => {
    const endTimeNow = Date.now();
    const elapsedMilliseconds = endTimeNow - startTime;
    const totalSeconds = Math.floor(elapsedMilliseconds / 1000);
    const minutes = Math.floor(totalSeconds / 60);
    const seconds = totalSeconds % 60;
    console.log('Elapsed time:', minutes, 'minutes', seconds, 'seconds');
    setEndTime(endTimeNow);
  };

  const delivery = async () => {
    if (scannedData.length === 0) {
      Alert.alert('DOCUMENT NOT CONFIRM OR EMPTY \n\n', 'PLEASE SCAN AT LEAST ONE DOCUMENT BEFORE DELIVERY.');
      return;
    }

    const allItemsSelected = scannedData.every(item => item.selected);
  
    if (allItemsSelected) {
      setScannedData([]);
      navigate.navigate('HOME');
      console.log(scannedData.map(item => item.data).join('\n'));
      endTimer();
      try {
        let { status } = await Location.requestForegroundPermissionsAsync();
        if (status !== 'granted') {
          Alert.alert('Permission denied', 'Please enable location access to use this feature.');
          return;
        }
  
        let location = await Location.getCurrentPositionAsync({});
  
        console.log('Location tracked:', location.coords.latitude, location.coords.longitude);
        // You can save the location data or send it to a server
      } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error getting location:', error);
        Alert.alert('Location error', 'Failed to get current location.');
      }
    } else {
      // Display alert message indicating that all rows need to be ticked
      Alert.alert('DOCUMENT NOT CONFIRM OR EMPTY \n\n', 'PLEASE CHECK AND CONFIRM ALL THE DOCUMENT BEFORE DELIVERY.');
    }
  };

  if (hasPermission === null) {
    return <Text>Requesting for camera permission</Text>;
  }
  if (hasPermission === false) {
    return <Text>No access to camera</Text>;
  }

  return (
    <View style={styles.cameraContainer}>
      
      <Camera
        onBarCodeScanned={scanned ? undefined : handleBarCodeScanned}
        style={StyleSheet.absoluteFillObject}
        //flashMode={torchOn ? Camera.Constants.FlashMode.torch : Camera.Constants.FlashMode.off}
      />
      <View style={styles.frame}>
        <Image source={require('../image/QR.png')} />
        {scanned && showScannedDataAlert()}
      </View>
      


      <Animatable.View
        animation={isPopped ? 'slideInUp' : 'slideOutDown'}
        duration={200}
        style={[
          styles.dataContainer,
          { bottom: isPopped ? -200 : -650 }
        ]}
      >
        <View style={styles.titlehead}>
          <Text style={styles.title}>Scanned DO List</Text>
          <TouchableOpacity style={[{ flexDirection: 'column' }, { alignItems: 'center' }, { marginRight: 20 }]} onPress={rescan}>
            <Image style={styles.checkboxIcon} source={require('../image/rescan.png')} />
            <Text style={[styles.headerbtntxt, { color: 'red' }]}>Rescan</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
          <TouchableOpacity style={[{ flexDirection: 'column' }, { alignItems: 'center' }, { marginRight: 20 }]} onPress={handleCheckButtonPress}>
            <Image style={styles.checkboxIcon} source={require('../image/file.png')} />
            <Text style={styles.headerbtntxt}>Check</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
        <ScrollView style={[styles.border ,]}>
  <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row', flexWrap: 'wrap'}}>
  {Array.isArray(scannedData) && scannedData.map((item, index) => (
  <View key={index} style={{ width: '50%', paddingHorizontal: 8 }}>
    <TouchableOpacity style={styles.row} onPress={() => handleItemPress(index)}>
    <Ionicons name="document-text-outline" size={60} color="black" />
    <Text style={[{fontSize: 20, textAlign:'center'}]}>{`DO NO:\n${item.data.slice(-7)}`}</Text>
      {item.selected && (
        <View>
            <Ionicons name="checkmark-sharp" size={30} color="#34b233"/>
        </View>
      )}
    </TouchableOpacity>
  </View>
))}
  </View>


</ScrollView>
      </Animatable.View>
      <View style={[styles.footer,]}>
        {isSelectionPhase ? (
          <View style={[styles.buttonContainer]}>
            <TouchableOpacity style={[styles.button, {backgroundColor: "rgba(52, 178, 51, 0.8)", borderTopLeftRadius: 30}]} onPress={confirm}>
            <Ionicons name="checkmark-sharp" size={40} color="#ffffff"/>
              <Text style={[styles.buttonText,{paddingVertical: 5, color: 'white'}]}>Confirm</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
            <TouchableOpacity style={[styles.button, {backgroundColor: "rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.8)", borderTopRightRadius: 30}]} onPress={cancel}>
            <Ionicons name="close-sharp" size={40} color="#ffffff"/>
              <Text style={[styles.buttonText,{paddingVertical: 5, color: 'white'}]}>Cancel</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
          </View>
        ) : (
          <View style={styles.buttonContainer}>
            <TouchableOpacity style={styles.button} onPress={pop}>
            <Ionicons name="qr-code-sharp" size={55} color="#34b233"/>
              <Text style={[styles.buttonText,{paddingVertical: 5, color:'black'}]}>DO List</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
            <TouchableOpacity style={styles.button} onPress={delivery}>
              <Image style={styles.icon} source={require('../image/delivery.png')} />
              <Text style={[styles.buttonText,{paddingVertical: 5, color:'black'}]}>Delivery</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
          </View>
        )}
      </View>
    </View>
  );
}

Nothing happen before the expo@51 update, but the error shown in the image come out of nowhere. Since I do not understand the error as well, need explanation to let me have a clearer message
Do I need to redo everything or any ways to solve it ?
